# C# - WCF - inter-process communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, process

What is the best WCF binding to use for inter-process communication?

I have used WCF over local networks and it is amazing, and I'd like to use it for inter-process communication as well.  I do not want to expose the communication over the network, however.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) for inter-process communication on the same machine.  Use the [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) if you are crossing machine boundaries.  I've found this [flow chart](http://mohammedatef.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/select-wcf-binding-2/) helpful.

[image: WCF Binding Selection Flow Chart].

Comment: For same machine inter process communication use as Matt already said NetNamedPipeBinding. I have a very basic example on my blog to show how this can be achieved. [https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150814232144/http://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/)

Comment: For inter-process communication on same machine, what type of project should I create? `WCF Service Library` project or `WCF Service Application` project?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/wcf-difference-between-service-application-and-service-lib/

Comment: Thanks! Should go for WCF Service Library.