# How to communicate between processes?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I can come up only with serialization, using of WCF, etc.
But is there the standard common way for communication between 2 processes in .Net?

UPDATE: What I actually mean how to communicate between 2 processes locally when I do not need to use WCF, Remoting and network at all. Are there some ways of doing it? And I am interesting in more elegant ways than storing data to HDD or to database.

Comment: What type of communication? Do you mean sending commands back and forth, or are you only sending data?

Comment: Local or remote? Reliable or best effort? Synchronous or asynchronous (queued)? Point to point of pub-sub? One size does not fit all.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: locally, but is it different ways depending on your next options?

Comment: @Jordan: I mean local communication, not remote.

Comment: Re the Update: still no context (no 'why') but only some unsupported rejection of possible solutions.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: Sorry I thought it was clear from the question that I do not expect answers about WCF and storing data. My first sentence in the question "I can come up only with serialization, using of WCF, etc." seems to be clear.

Comment: @poke dude, you closed this question as duplicate while citing a closed question. so, this is catch-22. How to add an answer? eh?

Comment: @T.S. You don’t. This topic is not asking for answers because it is off-topic for the reason that is given in the linked question.

Comment: @poke Original is off-topic - sure. however, it has tremendous interest - 79K. Do you want a law or do you want justice?

Comment: @T.S. Interest is not relevant here. Feel free to go to meta if you disagree with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no other information, I would suggest using WCF with a named pipes configuration:

[What is the best choice for .NET inter-process communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)

Comment: which additional information is needed?

Comment: Just a few of the concerns raised above - do you have needs for message queuing, pub/sub, etc.  If you're just looking to invoke methods across processes, WCF is the recommenced method.  You'll probably run into a lot of ".NET Remoting", but as Anuj mentioned, it's kind of antiquated at this point.

Comment: I do not need message queuing, pub/sub, etc. but of course it is interesting to know what if I would? Does it mean that I need to use another ways (not WCF)?

Comment: I was about to go on a long diatribe talking about other non .net systems I would use until I came across this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx

Comment: Thank you for article, but nothing new for me there.

Comment: @gorik: WCF is the MS recommendation. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @Kramii: I was looking for this answer. Thank you. So the most suitable way - using of WCF. OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at .NET Remoting. But for all intents and purposes you shouldn't be using it unless you have explicit requirements that are satisfied by remoting like...in-process, cross-appdomain communication.

I would just look at WCF's NetNamedPipeBinding. It sounds like it's exactly what you want: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfipcsample.aspx

Also it seems this question has already been answered:

[Interprocess communication for Windows in C# (.NET 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-net-2-0)

[C# - WCF - inter-process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613586/c-wcf-inter-process-communication)

Comment: I knew about WCF, that is why I mentioned it in the question. What I have asked - is there COMMON way of doing it. In other words do Microsoft recommends something for doing it?